# How to upload an image of File type to Firebase Storage from Node.js with the Admin SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I have Angular running on the FrontEnd and Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js on the BackEnd. 
What I want to achieve is to allow the user to select an image from his computer, using a simple `<input>` of type `file`. When I receive the user image which is of type `File` on the Angular side, I want to send this to my Node.js server and let him upload it to the Firebase Storage. 
Here's how I'm sending the image to Node.js:

```
  method(imageInput): void {
    const image: File = imageInput.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', (event: any) => {
      const imageData = {
        source: event.target.result,
        file: image
      }

      this.myService.uploadImage(imageData.file).subscribe(
        (res) => {
          // image sent successfully 
        },
        (err) => {
           // error
        })
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  }
```

So on the Node.js side I don't see a way to upload this image. 
I'm trying:

```
      admin.storage().bucket().upload(imageFromAngular, { --> Here's the problem
        destination: "someDestination/",
        contentType: "image/png",
        metadata: {
          contentType: "image/png"
        }
    }).then(() => { 
        // send successful response
    }).catch(err => {
       // send error response
    });
```

The issue comes from the fact that the `upload` method only takes as a parameter the **path** to the image and the options. However in this case I can't pass the path to the image, rather I can pass the image itself. I read this - https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/ but I couldn't find anything that would suit my needs. 

What would be the correct way to do this ?

### Update:

Here's a more detailed explanation to the approach I took: 

I'm using the `arrayBuffer` method of the `image` File inside my `method`. This method returns a promise of type ArrayBuffer. I get the value and send it to my Server. 
The Server uses `Buffer.from(ArrayBuffer, 'base64')` to convert the data and then I can safely use the `save` API (https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save).

To get the image later on I use `download` - (https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a byte stream (or a `Buffer`) to Cloud Storage.

- `createWriteStream()` API for streaming data to Cloud Storage: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream
- `save()` API for writing buffered data to Cloud Storage: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save

Comment: Yes, it's what I did, will edit the answer to show exact solution

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the content type in the `createWriteStream()` method.

```
file.createWriteStream({metadata: {contentType: 'image/jpeg'}})
```